# Showing unique Months & years of posts + filter them - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

i have a simple blog system where i want to show an archive in the sidebar which shows all Months & years of the blogposts. The blogposts have a Created_at & updated_at value in the database in this format: `2016-04-20 12:05:10` But when i do this:

```
<ul>
@foreach($blogposts as $post)
  <li class="bow-item"> <a href="#">{{$post->created_at->format('F Y')}}</a> </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

i obviously get repeated values if blogposts have the same Month & year. How do i get the unique months & years + will i be able to sort based on that month or year and get multiple posts? Because if i get unique values i probably will get only 1 post when i filter the results.

**Update:** 
You can do something like this

```
$dates = DB::table('blogposts')
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get([
        DB::raw('YEAR(`created_at`) AS `year`'),
        DB::raw('MONTH(`created_at`) AS `month`'),
    ]);
```

The problem is that my values are saved as an integer with this approach. But i would like to format the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you could run the whole raw query:

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        created_at
    FROM blogposts
    GROUP BY YEAR(created_at) DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC
";
$dates = DB::select($query);
```

---

Or this might work (untested and might not work):

```
$dates = DB::table('blogposts')
    ->select('created_at')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

*Query:*

```
$dates = DB::table('blogposts')
     ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name'))
     ->distinct()
     ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
     ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
     ->get();
```

*Output:*

```
@foreach($dates as $date) 
    {{ $date->month_name }}, {{ $date->year }} <br>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like this:

```
$periods = DB::table('blogposts')
    ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name)
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Then output like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($periods as $period)
    <li class="bow-item"> <a href="#">{{$period->year}} - {{$period->month_name}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```